# Creating a script to connect to ssh from nmap output

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to make a script to connect to server via ssh but i'm a bash noob. I do not know the ip and have to use nmap to scan the range. What i want is a script to connect or try to connect to the ip's from nmap output. (with try i mean one of the ips would be my ip, so connecting to this one is useless)

All i got so far is scanning the range with `namp -sP 192.168.42.1/24`

I have found an nmap filter to only scan for port 22
Here is what I get.

```
$ nmap --open -p22 192.168.42.*

Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-04-08 08:55 CEST

Nmap scan report for 192.168.42.113

Host is up (0.0057s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 59.63 seconds
```

Comment: if you get more than one ip with ssh open in that range....then?

Comment: no only ssh to one ip, but the output will have 2. One my and one of the host i want to connect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use netcat which is fast.nmap takes too long to scan range.

```
for i in {1..254..1}
do
  if nc -w 1 -zv 192.168.42.$i 22 &>> /dev/null
  then
  ssh 192.168.42.$i
  fi
done
```

Comment: After the script stops it kicks me out of ssh and im on my normal shell again. Maybe an endless loop? So i just need to ctrl +c

Comment: Okay it worked but it took some time to scan the range, like 30 sec.

Comment: update this on line 6 from ```fi``` to ```fi &```.then it runs in parallel